# tree with branch

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I want to draw the following picture in Tikz (I drew this in **ipe**).

[image]

I am only able to draw the following picture using the code below.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   grow'=up,
  sibling distance = 3cm
]
  \coordinate 
    child {
        child {node {}}
        child {node {}}
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone please help me to draw the picture using Tikz?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try with `tikz-qtree` which have nice documentation ...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Let me have a look to the documentation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I tried but unable to do it. It will b great if you give me some hints regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

This is relatively easy by use of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes 
    minimum width = 4em,
            delay = {where content={}{shape=coordinate}{},
% tree
    calign=fixed edge angles,
    calign angle=60,      
    grow=north,
          },
      }
% tree body
[
    [
        [
            [,tier=L]
            [
                []
                []
            ]
        ]
    [~,phantom,fit=band]
        [
            [,tier=L]
            [
                [,tier=L]
                []
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```