# How to draw Y type tree with qtree or tikz-qtree

Tags: forest, tikz-qtree, tikz-pic, qtree

Is it possible to draw unlabelled tree of the below type with qtree or tikz-qtree? Any suggestion..
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `forest` package. The idea is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600915/tree-with-branch/602011#602011).

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            % nodes 
            minimum width = 8em,
            delay = {where content={}{shape=coordinate}{},
                % tree
                calign=fixed edge angles,
                calign angle=40, %angle between two nodes     
                grow=north, %direction of forest grow 
            },
        }
        % tree body
        [
          [
            [
              [,tier=L]
              %[
                %[]
                [,tier=L]
              %]
            ]
            [,phantom,fit=band]
            [
              [,tier=L]
              %[
                [,tier=L]
                %[]
              %]
            ]
          ]
        ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]